# Make copy of record and save to database but with unique id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to make a new record that is an exact copy of an existing record, but I need the new record to of course to have a unique `id`.  Meaning: I do not want to copy over the `id` from the existing record to the new record.

Current code

```
@blog = Blog.new(title: "some title")
@blog.save

@copy_of_existing_blog = Blog.new(@blog.attributes)
@copy_of_existing_blog.save
```

It returns this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

I understand why it is erroring out.  It is attempting to save a record that has a duplicate `id` of an existing record.  I just do not know how to make an exact copy of a record, minus the `id`, and save it to the database.

Comment: Is the id auto incrementing in the database ??

Comment: @MamadouLamineNiang yes it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to filter out the ID from the attributes hash. ActiveSupport has a handy [`Hash#except`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) method which does just this:

```
Blog.new(@blog.attributes.except("id"))
```

Additionally you may want to filter out the timestamps as well.

Comment: `.except` does the exact same thing as in [Зелёный s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666985/make-copy-of-record-and-save-to-database-but-with-unique-id/36667098#36667098) under the hood.

Comment: This is correct answer but key should be a string instead of symbol `Blog.new(@blog.attributes.except("id"))`

Comment: You should be aware about the `id` key from the `attributes` method. 
This can work `@blog.attributes.except(:id)` or this `@blog.attributes.except("id")`, bcause attributes return a simple hash with keys like a string, not `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. ps now fine + 1

Comment: Edited, forgot that attributes is not indifferent access. Thanks.

Comment: The reason you might want to filter out the timestamps is that any caches may not be properly invalidated if the "duplicated" Blog record has the same timestamps as the old record.

Comment: Awesome point to filter out the timestamps as well.  Didn't think about that.  Thanks!